# There are six of them today

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

All six are different.
If we sort by small to large
from the beginning, the third, fourth and sixth are the same.
It was designed by the sculptor.
Society over the smallest a drawing has been placed to warn.

Comment: If sort them and the 4th is equal to the 6th, then the 5th is equal too.

Comment: @Davide They are sorted only by size. If third to sixth are of the same *size*, why does it follow that they have to all be identical, even if three of them are 'the same' for some reason?

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick oh I got it.